# Prepopulate post_title and post_content When Adding New Event For The Events Calendar Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the plugin [The Events Calendar](https://theeventscalendar.com/product/wordpress-events-calendar/) for my WordPress site.  I want to do the following process:

- Create a button on the front-end for each post labeled as "+ Add Demo".  This button is ultimately a link to the back-end "Add New Event" screen.  The link passes in the `ID` of the `post`.
- At the "Add New Event" screen, I want to first find the `post` by the passed in `ID` and extract out the `post_content` and the `post_title` of that `post`, and prepopulate the event with that data.

Ultimately, it will look something like this with the data prepopulated on the "Add New Event" screen:

[image: Add Event Screen]

Sources I have already explored:

- I was hoping it would be a simple matter of overriding a template in the `The Events Calendar` plugin, so I looked at the documentation section titled: [Themer's Guide](https://support.theeventscalendar.com/153124-Themers-Guide).  I could be missing something, but I couldn't find the template to override.  I think this might be because, on this form, the plugin is essentially reusing the back-end post templates, and I'm not not sure where those templates are located and how to override them.
- I figured it might be a matter of finding the right [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/), but I was having trouble finding the right hook for this particular situation.

I know how to create the button on the front-end which creates a link to the "Add New Event" screen.  But here is my ultimate question:

**Question:** How can I hook into that "Add New Event" form by grabbing the `post_title` and the `post_content` of the passed in post's `ID`, and then prepopulate the form with that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  In case anyone is curious, solution is below.

First, here is the button:

```
<?php
  calendar_params = "/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=tribe_events&id_to_pass_in=" . get_the_ID();
?>
<a href="<?php echo site_url($calendar_params) ?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Demo</a>
```

The solution was ultimately to make use of the `default_title` and `default_content` filter hooks:

```
function test_the_events_calendar_prepopulate_demo_title( $post_title, $post) {
  if($post->post_type == "tribe_events" && array_key_exists("id_to_pass_in", $_REQUEST)){
    $demo_post = get_post( ((int) $_REQUEST["id_to_pass_in"]) );
    if(!empty($demo_post)){
      $demo_post_title = $demo_post->post_title;
      return $demo_post_title;
    }
  }
}

function test_the_events_calendar_prepopulate_demo_content( $post_content, $post) {
  if($post->post_type == "tribe_events" && array_key_exists("id_to_pass_in", $_REQUEST)){
    $demo_post = get_post( ((int) $_REQUEST["id_to_pass_in"]) );
    if(!empty($demo_post)){
      $demo_post_content = $demo_post->post_content;
      return $demo_post_content;
    }
  }
}

add_filter('default_title', 'test_the_events_calendar_prepopulate_demo_title', 10, 2);
add_filter('default_content', 'test_the_events_calendar_prepopulate_demo_content', 10, 2);
```